# Attach a previousle created persistant disk to a Google Compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had deleted an instance with the following command :

```
gcloud compute instances delete --keep-disks jupyter-test
```

Now I want to create an instance with the disk I kept.

At first I used :

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container jupyter-test  --container-image jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

I got the following error message :

```
The resource 'projects/PROJECT/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/jupyter-test' already exists
```

Then I tried :

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container jupyter-test --disk name=jupyter-test  --container-image jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

But I got the same error message. I know it already exists, that's why I want to use it again !

Comment: Did you try this option: --boot-disk-device-name=, what you are trying to do is use an already existing boot disk not just only attaching a disk.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue and found that in your command flag --disk is missing an ‘equal to’. Moreover, I needed to run the command as beta to make it to work.

The command below worked:

gcloud beta compute instances NAME create-with-container jupyter-test
 --disk=name=NAME--container-image IMAGE